# How to implement Open with menu in flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video, package

I have seen many music players or other applications written using flutter but none of them have a `open with` menu.

To be clear, I mean how to make my music player/ other app to show in that open with menu, like if I want to access a music from files and my app comes in that menu.

Is there any way to do that, cause I can't find it, nor can I found any issues related to it.

[image: open with samsung]

Above is the `open with` menu displayed in Samsung, similar type of menu are their on other android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Open with` menu is a native function provided by the OS. The menu looks the same in different apps on the same phone, but it looks differently on other phones.

To trigger this menu within a Flutter app, we could use a package like [`open_file`](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file), which invokes the native OS method to open a file:

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.txt");
```

If more than one app is assigned to that specific file extension, the `Open with` menu will appear and prompt the end-user with the app selection.

---

That said, based on your scenario, it's totally possible to create a custom `Open with` menu for your app, although it's recommended to use what the OS natively offers to us.

Comment: Sorry, I found out that open_file plugin is used for calling an opening file request that's not what I wanted, I wanted my app to show in Open with menu like my music player comes in that menu. I hope I am clear.